# Can't find docker-compose running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to stop a container generated by a `docker-compose up` but I can't find where this docker-compose was started. If I try to kill the docker container it is automatically recreated (as expected since it is docker-compose).

When running the command `docker-compose ps` in the folder containing the `docker-compose.yml` file I get an empty result, so it should be somewhere else...

How can I find where the docker compose is running and finally stop it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `docker ps -a | grep <certain_container>`

Use `locate docker-compose.yml` and find the one that you want
Use `docker-compose down`

Comment: as for @leeman24 answer, that didn't work for me (yes I executed `down` as well, no luck)

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1:**

Install `docker-compose` which would be available on your path using the official instructions - https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/.

You can then go to the folder containing the `docker-compose.yml` and run `docker-compose down`.

**Option #2:**

Search for the file using something like:

```
find / -name "docker-compose"
```

You can then use the absolute path when running the command.

**Option #3:**

Update your containers restart policy:

```
docker update --restart=no container_name
```

Comment: I used `locate -br "docker-compose.y"` and then executed `docker-compose -f /file/path stop` on every path generated by the locate but I can still see the Portainer docker container... Isn't there any smarter way from docker to show all the running compose?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question since you mentioned "When running the command docker-compose ps in the folder containing the docker-compose.yml file I get an empty result." which lead me to believe that you were missing the actual executable file `docker-compose` rather than not knowing the path to your `docker-compose.yml` file. If your only goal is to stop it, use Option #3 to set the restart policy to no and then you can manually kill the containers which will not be recreated.

Comment: If you actually went through all the `docker-compose.yml` files and still didn't stop the containers it is possible that someone else has deleted the files OR the file is named `another-name.yml`.

Comment: probably that's what happened... I tried your Option #3 as well but didn't work, sorry :(

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the `docker inspect container_name` and maybe the output of option 3. If the container restart policy was set to no, the container shouldn't restart after being killed.